# How to connect Internet from Virtualbox?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 with Virtualbox and now I am trying to connect Internet from Virtualbox.

I am getting below "There is no Internet connection" error. Is there any way to connect Internet from virtualbox?

I am using Windows 10 and I have connected Internet with ethernet cable without any problem.

[image]

Virtualbox network settings;

[image]

The green dot on network logo sometimes goes to red;

[image]

Windows network adapters;

[image]

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/363003/no-internet-connection-on-virtualbox-windows-7-as-guest-ubuntu-13-04-as-host

Comment: Did you bridge the network connections? You can do that by selecting "Ethernet" and "Virtualbox Host-Only Network", right-clicking, then selecting "Bridge Connections" (you must be admin to do this).

Answer (score 1):

I've set mine to NAT and this works for Ubuntu Debian with XFCE4 desktop (Linux xxxxxxxx 4.9.0-6-686 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.82-1+deb9u3 (2018-03-02) i686 GNU/Linux). See image below (in Dutch, however, the settings will be clear I presume).

[image: Virtual Box (v 5.2.8) Settings]

However, I also have a basic minimal headless install (Linux debian 4.9.0-3-686 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.30-2+deb9u3 (2017-08-06) i686) with same settings that doesn't automatically connect to the network / internet. In this VM I have to enter on a terminal:

```
sudo dhclient eth0
```

(or whatever your network card's name is).